# Processing incoming websocket stream in python

Tags: python, opencv, websocket

There is a server written in Go that sends me a video stream via WebSocket. I want to capture this stream in a Python program and use OpenCV to process it. However, the incoming stream seems to have a specific type of codec that makes it unable for me to process it.

Here is my code snippet that connects to the WebSocket stream:

```
def on_open(ws):
    print("opened")

def on_message(ws, message):
    print(message)

def on_close(ws):
    print("closed connection")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    socket = "ws://192.168.1.104:8080/stream/demo2/channel/0/mse?uuid=demo2&channel=0"
    ws = websocket.WebSocketApp(socket,
                                on_open=on_open,
                                on_message=on_message,
                                on_close=on_close)
    ws.run_forever()
```

And here is some part a single message printed out:

> b'\x00\x00\x00\xa8moof\x00\x00\x00\x10mfhd\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00\x90traf\x00\x00\x00\x14tfhd\x00\x02\x00 \x00\x00\x00\x01\x01\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x14tfdt\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xc6\xfc\x00\x00\x00`trun\x00\x00\x0b\x05\x00\x00\x00\x06\x00\x00\x00\xb0\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0b\xf4\x00\x00\r8\x00\x00\x00Z\x00\x00\x0b\x9a\x00\x00\ra\x00\x00\x00Z\x00\x00\r\xb6\x00\x00\r:\x00\x00\x00Z\x00

Any idea on how to capture this video and process it using OpenCV?

P.S. I have tried `cv2.imdecode(message)` but I got the `bad argument` error message.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the server sends a raw binary image with a given shape and assuming it is contained in a complete frame as a blob  (e.g. without frame header information), and furthermore assuming that you know the shape of the image, then you could read it like

```
import numpy as np

shape = (480, 640, 3)
image = np.frombuffer(message, dtype=np.uint8).reshape(shape)

# eventually, you need cv2.imdecode(), if it's jpeg etc.
```

It would be much better if the server would encode the image as jpeg and then in base64 and put it in a json object before sending. Then you can decode it like

```
import base64
import numpy as np
import cv2

image = cv2.imdecode(np.frombuffer(base64.b64decode(base64_image), dtype=np.uint8), cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
```

(base64_image being the string received within the json object containing the base64 encoded jpeg image)

This way, the receiver does not have to have knowledge about the image shape.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I can ask for such modifications from the server maintainer. However, doesn't it affect the latency of the video stream?

Comment: Depends. jpeg/base64 encoding requires computing power, while sending raw images requires network bandwidth. Which is faster depends on the environment and the type of images.

Comment: Thanks! Another follow-up question: this stream is also used by the front-end (streamed video is shown on the webpage). Does this encoding affect the front-end visualizaation?

Comment: On the web front end you can directly render base64 encoded jpeg images by simply assigning the base64 string to an img tag: `<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64, + base64_image" />`

Comment: Thanks! Since we're working with video, is it the same thing?

Comment: If you send individual frames by frame, it is the same. If you are streaming - not. Streaming videos is very different from sending images. Very often, we send individial frames fast (e.g. > 5 fps) and this appears like a moving video. On the web front-end you would use htm video player for streaming, not img tags.

Comment: The video is being streamed (not frame by frame), as mentioned in the question. What is the solution in this case?

Comment: There are quite a couple of different streaming protocols and libraries. Maybe this one is a start: `https://pypi.org/project/python-ffmpeg-video-streaming/` . You need to know which type of streaming protocol is used.